# Semantic segmentation of lesions

Tags: deep-learning, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I need your lights please.I try to segment lesions from fundus images and i am completely lost.I chose to create a very limited dataset of only 87 train & 16 test images of 640x640.
As you see the val_dice coefficient is almost 81% while the val_loss is 50.

[image]

My question is if these ***results justify those images***.

[image]

Here is my code
[Code From Google Collab](https://www.ppaste.org/r6WxSCB52)

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps more diverse training data is needed?

Comment: I have used much more data with worse results....